# How should baseball card commons be stored?

Tags: baseball, collectibles, cards, maintenance

Generally when you buy a large number of baseball cards you're going to get a ton of common and uncommon cards. Obviously you want rare or special cards to be kept separate and be well maintained, but the bulk of your collection is going to be common cards.

I'm planning to start collecting again soon and would like to have a good idea of what kind of storage I should plan on obtaining for the bulk of my collection.

What storage solutions exist that make these cards easy to access, keep them in fair condition and do not take up too much space? I'm especially interested in solutions that readily expand to take on more cards.

Answer (score 2):

This question really comes down to how much money you want to spend on the preservation of your collection.

On the low end of the spectrum (and perfectly suitable), you could put all commons in penny sleeves and a top loader. Then put them into a square tupper ware container to protect against water and what not. The downside is where they're stored once they're in the container. You want to avoid to much heat, and to much moisture. This leads me to...

Climate controlled storage. With climate controlled storage you're going to ensure that your cards are never to hot or to moist which will guarantee their preservation.

For my money, penny sleeves + top loads + square tupper ware container + closet thats in neither the attic nor the basement but somewhere in between.